# In Meteor Methods this.connection is always undefined

Tags: meteor

I am trying to implement some methods for a DDP API, for use with a C# remote client.

Now, I want to be able to track the connection to implement some type of persistent session, to this end, id hope to be able to use the session id given by DDP on connection, example:

```
{
   "msg": "connected",
   "session": "CmnXKZ34aqSnEqscR"
}
```

After reading the documentation, I see that inside meteor methods, I can access the current connection using "this.connection", however, I always get an undefined "this.connection".

Was it removed? If so, how can i access it now?

PS: I dont want to login as a user and access this.userId, since the app I want to create should not login, but actually just get a document id and do work associated with that, including changes to other collections, but all, regarding ONLY this id, and I dont want to have to include this id every time I call a function, since, this could possibly lead security problems if anyone can just send any id. The app would ideally do a simple login, then associate token details with his "session".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a file named ".next.js" to force meteor to use the newest unsupported javascript spec using a package.

Somehow this messed it up. Changed back to default javascript and it now works.

Thank you :)

Comment: I have an app with the harmony package and next.js files where this.connection works as expected.  I have seen tough to trace errors caused by using '=>' when defining a method.

Comment: I was using => for defining methods, I guess thats the reason.

What is the correct way to define the methods when using "this"?

I was doing : () => { this.connection; }

Answer (score 1):

Changing from:

```
() => { this.connection; }
```

to:

```
function() { this.connection; }
```

solves the problem from me. Based on a comment in the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks!  I was using `'methodName': () => { this.connection; }` but was always undefined, changed to `'methodName': function() { this.connection; }` and now I have access to this.connection.

Answer (score 0):

The C# client on github has a few bugs with it as it doesn't follow the DDP spec exactly. When you send commands to it to connect and run a call, it usually sends the '.call' too soon.

The method does work if you do it this way with `this.connection` on the server side Meteor method.

You need to make sure you send the method calls after you know that you are actually connected. This is what works at least with Meteor 0.8.2

Comment: What C# client are you talking about? I am not sure.
I am using my own C# created client. I also have one in C++. However, I am currently testing using a plain javascript client.

I get the same exact error when using the Dev tools when navigating to the actual meteor page and calling Meteor.call too.

Comment: @SilentWarrior can you provide a minimal repro of it, I use DDP externally quite heavily, including this connection to get the headers

Comment: @SilentWarrior there's really only one case there the Meteor method will have an empty `.connection`, when you do `Meteor.call` from the server side in Meteor

Answer (score 0):

init.coffee

```
Meteor.startup ->
    # client init
    if Meteor.isClient
        Meteor.call "init"
```

methods.coffee

```
Meteor.methods
    init: ->
        console.log @connection.httpHeaders.host
```

it's that easy...